# After system state restore: SBS Baseline Configuration Analyzer 2.0 stopped working

Tags: best-practices, small-business

So the system drive of our SBS 2011 server has crashed. We had a backup which we used to perform a systemstate recovery and non-authorative restore of Active Directory. Since the restore, we cannot run the SBS 2011 Best Practices Analyzer, which fails halfway trough the scan, with this message:

`Microsoft Baseline Configuration Analyzer 2.0 stopped working.`

I've looked at the BPA log file, it has no real conslusion on why the scan is not working. Other than `MBCA.exe exited with return code -532459699`

Also, our [Sharepoint services](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200509/after-system-state-restore-exception-from-hresult-0x80020009-disp-e-exceptio) are not functioning at this moment. I know various softwares on the SBS 2011 are tightly bound together, so this may or may not be related to the problem above.

What do we need to do to get the BPA up and running again?

Comment: Do you have more than one Domain Controller?

Comment: No, the SBS 2011 is the only DC in our domain